# PHP reply-to error - need person's email, not admin

Tags: php

I have the below PHP contact form that has a CAPTCHA code to ensure is correct. However, when I reply to the email from the website it puts a random email which i believe is the server admin, however, I want it to be the persons email who sent the form in. below is the code, could you possibly be able to help me?

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   if( $_SESSION['chapcha_code'] == $_POST['chapcha_code'] && !empty    ($_SESSION['chapcha_code'] ) ) {
$youremail = 'info@example.com';
$fromsubject = 'www.example.co.uk';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$to = $youremail; 
$mailsubject = 'Message from Website'.$fromsubject.' Contact Page';
$body = $fromsubject.'

The person that contacted you is:  '.$fname.'
 Phone Number: '.$phone.'
 E-mail: '.$mail.'
 Subject: '.$subject.'

 Message: 
 '.$message.'


|---------END MESSAGE----------|'; 
echo "Thank you for your message. I will contact you shortly if needed.<br/>Go to <a     href='/index.html'>Home Page</a>"; 
                            mail($to, $subject,     $body);
    unset($_SESSION['chapcha_code']);
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, you have provided an invalid security code';
}
} else { 
echo "You must write a message. </br> Please go to <a href='/contact.html'>Contact Page</a>"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some headers so the from address is the users mail.

Also refer to the [mail docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

try this

```
$headers = "From: $mail\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $mail\r\n";


mail($to, $subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I now get a Syntax error... not sure where it is supposed to be added? any help would be greatly appreciated.